# blueprint css rails 3.1 help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My blueprint css works on my local machine, but when I push to heroku I get an error.

I have blueprint stored in my `app/assets/stylesheets folder` and here are the stylesheet tags I'm using:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
```

In my heroku logs, it says application.css isnt precompiled and I think that might be the error, but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my heroku logs:

```
2011-09-04T07:35:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2011-09-04T07:36:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2011-09-04T07:36:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to created
2011-09-04T07:36:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-04T07:36:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-09-04T07:36:01+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-09-04T07:36:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-04T07:36:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 44288 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-09-04T07:36:07+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
2011-09-04T07:36:07+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-09-04T07:36:07+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:44288, CTRL+C to stop
2011-09-04T07:36:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-09-04T08:41:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2011-09-04T08:41:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2011-09-04T08:41:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-09-04T08:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-09-04T08:41:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-04T16:05:59+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2011-09-04T16:06:10+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 9ec665f by XXXXXXXX@yahoo.com
2011-09-04T16:06:10+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by XXXXXXXX@yahoo.com
2011-09-04T16:06:11+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-09-04T16:06:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2011-09-04T16:06:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to created
2011-09-04T16:06:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-04T16:06:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 32066 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-09-04T16:06:25+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
2011-09-04T16:06:25+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-09-04T16:06:25+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:32066, CTRL+C to stop
2011-09-04T16:06:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-09-04T16:06:27+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:27+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 65.7.186.42 at 2011-09-04 09:06:27 -0700
2011-09-04T16:06:28+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:28+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2011-09-04T16:06:28+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2011-09-04T16:06:28+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:28+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2011-09-04T16:06:28+00:00 heroku[router]: GET corporatefox.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=754ms status=404 bytes=728
2011-09-04T16:06:28+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 65.7.186.42 - - [04/Sep/2011:09:06:28 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30" corporatefox.heroku.com
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pages/home" for 65.7.186.42 at 2011-09-04 09:06:35 -0700
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (17.0ms)
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (25.3ms)
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 92ms
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_layouts__stylesheets_html_erb__1720273165801032019_31408840'
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1444640675865794326_32133320'
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /pages/home] miss
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 heroku[router]: GET corporatefox.heroku.com/pages/home dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=120ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-09-04T16:06:35+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 65.7.186.42 - - [04/Sep/2011:09:06:35 -0700] "GET /pages/home HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30" corporatefox.heroku.com
2011-09-04T16:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 65.7.186.42 at 2011-09-04 09:06:42 -0700
2011-09-04T16:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2011-09-04T16:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2011-09-04T16:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:06:42+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2011-09-04T16:06:42+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 65.7.186.42 - - [04/Sep/2011:09:06:42 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30" corporatefox.heroku.com
2011-09-04T16:14:42+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2011-09-04T16:14:53+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 2fed989 by foxgrade@yahoo.com
2011-09-04T16:14:53+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by foxgrade@yahoo.com
2011-09-04T16:14:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to bouncing
2011-09-04T16:14:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from bouncing to created
2011-09-04T16:14:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-04T16:14:54+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-09-04T16:14:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-09-04T16:14:56+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-09-04T16:14:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-04T16:14:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 48112 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-09-04T16:15:01+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
2011-09-04T16:15:01+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-09-04T16:15:01+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:48112, CTRL+C to stop
2011-09-04T16:15:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (13.2ms)
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (24.1ms)
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 86ms
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET corporatefox.heroku.com/pages/home dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=755ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_layouts__stylesheets_html_erb__4527639971944011061_33003340'
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2040511387187567951_33642800'
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /pages/home] miss
2011-09-04T16:15:02+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 65.7.186.42 - - [04/Sep/2011:09:15:02 -0700] "GET /pages/home HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30" corporatefox.heroku.com
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just had the same problem. I solved it by setting `config.assets.compile = true` in `config/environments/production.rb`

EDIT: This works fine while developing, but has a performance penalty as compilation is performed in run-time. See the answer below for a better solution

Comment: No problem. Started trying out both Heroku and Rails today, so there might be another way. I guess one should rather compile them up front somehow, although it seemed they would be cached anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443536/blueprint-screen-css-isnt-precompiled - did not work.

Comment: You rock.  I've been struggling through this to figure it out.

Comment: This solution may work, but it is not the ideal solution. By setting compile = true, you're compiling assets in runtime, which has performance costs. The ideal solution is Martin Frank's answer. You need to rake assets:precompile every time you deploy your app to a production environment. It's more performant to precompile the assets.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been working all night trying to figure this out, and your solution worked. +1

Answer (score 13):

One way to fix this is to precompile the assets by running `rake assets:precompile`. You have to include a javascript runtime for this by adding

```
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"a
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

to the `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`.

Comment: For future readers: this answer is more ideal than the selected answer. The high-performance solution is to precompile (as this answer says), not to set compile=true.

Comment: You also have to explicitly tell Rails to include the Blueprint CSS files in the precompilation. To config/environments/production.rb, add `config.assets.precompile += %w( blueprint/screen.css blueprint/print.css blueprint/ie.css )`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443536/blueprint-screen-css-isnt-precompiled.  Then precompile *for production* with `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. This Heroku article explains the three options for compiling assets:  http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar. Do all this *before* pushing to Heroku.

Comment: @MarkBerry thank you! I had the same problem and it is solved now. How about images do they need to be added too?

Comment: @Shvetusya- Looks like my images were automatically included. Check your `public/assets` folder to see the precompiled assets.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( blueprint/screen.css blueprint/print.css )
```

in 
    `config/environments/production.rb`

I'm sure someone with more experience than me can tell us why all css files aren't pre-compiled as standard.  I'm only just starting out too!

Here's at least one discussion:
[Rails 3.1 asset pipeline - missing files from public/assets - why isn't this the default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415449/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-missing-files-from-public-assets-why-isnt-this-the)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run rake assets:precompile and couldn't get it to work. I have the assets group in my Gemfile. I read somewhere that I should make sure to precompile the production env:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

That didn't help either. I ended up doing the config.assets.compile = true, which worked fine, but I would love to get the real solution to work.

I never get the `-----> Preparing Rails asset pipeline` when pushing to heroku that they say one should get.