# running rails 3.2 / mongoid app on heroku fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mongoid

I'd like to now if anybody could help me with my heroku deployement.

I've set up my Rails 3.2 app with the following Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'mongoid_slug'
gem 'heroku'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem "compass", ">= 0.12.alpha"

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

And I have run the `rails g mongoid:config` command

From the heroku support, I've added the mongolab extension and changed the mongoid.yml evironnement variables to `MONGOLAB_URI`

When I then deploy the app, it doesn't run on heroku.

I'm not sure what is going on, but i get this error message in the Heroku logs:

```
WARNING:  Invalid .gemspec format in '/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/specifications/actionmailer-3.2.0.gemspec'
2012-01-29T19:13:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not find activemodel-3.2.0 in any of the sources
```

here is the full log file:

https://gist.github.com/1700231

has anybody experienced the same issue? I'm not sure if the problem comes from my set up or if I need to add something to rails to work with mongoid?

Cheers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721712/deploying-to-rails-project-to-heroku-could-not-find-activemodel

Comment: No I haven't but I will try when I get back home. Will try this too: http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html. not sure if it can be stack related.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a bit of pain int the b*tt, but I'm finally there.

http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html

is the right place to go to deplay rails 3.2 on heroku.

This said my head hurt, not too much fun to get so many hurdles when one wants to learn.
Octopress looks fine  at the moment I tell you :)

Alright let's keep going