# Error Deploying to Heroku with Rails 3.2.1 / Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongohq

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057717/running-rails-3-2-mongoid-app-on-heroku-fails) I'm having problems with deploying to Heroku on Rails 3.2.1 (Ruby 1.9.3-p125 - although I did set up Heroku to run with Ruby 1.9.3-p0). I followed all the steps in the [Rails apps tutorial](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html) but my app is crashing when I try to view it in production.

Here is a copy of my heroku logs:

http://pastebin.com/7J53p9Vt

And my gemfile:

http://pastebin.com/M4TE143i

Thx!

Comment: can you connect to the console?  `heroku run console`

Comment: Sure, so I can connect to the console on heroku. I get a few deprecation warnings though but that's about it - http://pastebin.com/CwKj9HwL

Comment: I haven't added a proc file since I'm using the Thin web server - from what I understood if you declare the Thin gem in your Gemfile, Heroku sets up an appropriate web process without requiring a Procfile.